# Как оптимизировать постраничный вывод из большого объема данных?

Tags: mysql, sql, производительность, highload

Есть большая выборка данных (50 млн.), надо вывести из нее первые 10 записей по наиболее свежей дате (после чего подзагружать еще по 10 записей). Сложность в том, что данные сгруппированы в 10 разделов (в каждом от 2-3 до 10 млн. записей) и выводить надо только данные из этого раздела.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type=1 ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 10;
```

По этому запросу EXPLAIN показывает, что MySQL сначала выбирает несколько млн. строк, соответствующих нужному типу, после чего их сортирует по дате.

В таблице стоит составной индекс (type, updated), но он не сильно помогает. MySQL использует только первую его часть.

Тоже самое при выводе последующих страниц

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE type=1 AND updated<'offset' ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Как оптимизировать этот запрос?

Comment: Странно, topN сортировку по индексу mysql делать умеет. Какая версия СУБД? innodb? Если выбирать не всё, а только первичный ключ - ведёт себя так же?

Comment: да, InnoDB. пробовал и по первичному ключу, тоже самое. в целом поведение MySQL более чем логичное. даже с использованием индекса идет сначала поиск нужных значений по типу (а это несколько млн. записей), после чего они уже сортируются по дате.

Comment: полагаю, что надо использовать подход, где сначала идет сортировка по updated, после чего из нее выбираются уже 10 нужных записей (в соответствии с подходящим типом, т.к. ORDER BY нужен перед WHERE), но вопрос как это реализовать?

Comment: знающие люди подсказали, что есть курсоры MySQL, но пока изучаю как их правильно использовать.

Comment: Курсоры тут ни при чём, они позволяют сэкономить чуток памяти при обработке запроса, возвращающем очень много строк. По btree вычитать константный префикс и по нему же крайние N записей - это элементарная штука. Даже глупый mysql должен уметь backward index scan. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: а как это сделать в виде конкретного работающего запроса?

Comment: все это прекрасно работает, только backward index scan (по update) идет по большому количеству записей

Comment: А вот в том и дело, что запрос тот же самый. У вас идёт частичный просмотр дерева, по крайней мере как вы указываете в вопросе. А должен использовать и сортировку по этому же индексу. Поэтому версию СУБД и спросил, может у вас что-то очень древнее.

Comment: в том то все и дело, EXPLAIN выдает Using where и длину ключа, соответствующую только первой части индекса. А значение rows может достигать по 5-10 млн. записей.

Comment: а отдельный индекс по `updated`  тут ничем не поможет?

Comment: оптимальным по производительности оказалось решение, где используются разные индексы в зависимости от условия поиска (там используется фасеточный поиск с ограничением по типу, стране и городу). в самом простом случае используется индекс по update, в других - составные индексы по условиям поиска и update (например, (type, update)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге пришел к решению на уровне логики приложения. В основной базе постоянно содержится 0.5-1 млн наиболее свежих записей, а остальные выносятся в архивную. Скрипт-архиватор раз в сутки переносит старые записи в архив. Первоначально пользователям выдаются только наиболее свежие данные из основной базы (99% запросов), а если их недостаточно, то производится поиск в архивной.

P.S. В дополнение, если пользователь начал листать ленту - сделал вывод не 10, а 50 записей. При скроллинге клиент 1 раз выдает данные из запроса, а остальные 4 пакета помещает в массив и выдает по мере необходимости. Когда данные клиента заканчиваются, делается новый запрос. Сразу 50 не вывожу, чтобы не тормозить браузер (там много графики). Что-то подобное встречается в vk и ряде других крупных сайтов.

P.P.S. Итоговое решение на уровне MySQL получилось следующим. Провел вручную тестирование с выборками на основе жестко прописанного (use index) простого или составного индекса. Наилучшим по производительности оказалось использование составного индекса (например, (type, update)), использование которого жестко прописано в коде приложения в зависимости от конкретного типа выборки (по-умолчанию, в ряде случает MySQL выбирает не самый производительный индекс). Удивило расхождение данных, выдаваемых EXPLAIN с реальными показателями производительности. Так, простой индекс (EXPLAIN показывает rows 10) работал в сотни раз медленнее составного с rows в несколько млн. записей.

P.P.P.S. В общем, проблема была в неправильном выборе движком MySQL индекса по которому проводился поиск (в некоторых случаях использовался только простой индекс, когда лучше было использовать составной, а в некоторых поиск проводился сразу по 2-м индексам с объединением результатов). При прописывании USE INDEX вручную (на каждый конкретный случай) производительность многократно возросла.